# Restore Git repositoy

Tags: git, gitlab, phabricator

We had a Git server (Phabricator) for own project, but the server breakdown and now we need restore git repositories.

We have the backups of files below, so How restore this in new Git Server (GitLab)?

```
root@dev:/var/repo/repo/G# ls
branches  config  description  HEAD  hooks  info  objects  refs  teste.log  TESTE.log
```

Comment: ???? Every person who cloned that repo has a backup. You could just set up a new repo, then from one of the developers (the one who fetched/pulled from the repo most recently would be the best candidate) can push the branches into the new repo (settijg it up as a new remote).

Comment: Just `git push <server_url> --all` should work.

Comment: Thanks!!! This solved my problem.